# Using Google Sheets to scrape horse racing odds

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to google-sheets so have  a lot to learn, I'm wanting to scrape latest horse odds from daily races on https://www.racenet.com.au
An example URL would be

https://www.racenet.com.au/racing-form-guide/ararat-20191210/all-races

I am having trouble getting importxml to pick up any useful data no matter what parameters I try, can anyone give me any suggestions on the correct syntax and parameters to get the horse name and odds from this site...

Comment: Do you have some sort of code sample that you tried? This would be helpful for giving you a hand where you could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

the first step is to block JavaScript on a given website to see what left to be **scraped**:

[image]

Google Sheets does not support importing of JS elements

then the next step would be running the `IMPORTXML` formula to see stuff that can be scraped

```
=IMPORTXML("URL_here", "//*")
```

Comment: Thanks. I chose this site as it had no  Java script, it is turned off and still works. But setting parameter as //* displays just //*

Comment: did you try: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.racenet.com.au/racing-form-guide/ararat-20191210/all-races", "//*")` it returns me around 4000 rows of data